# Theorem Proof of Orthogonal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $v_1,...,v_n \in V$ are nonzero, mutually orthogonal elements
>   of an inner product space V. Then $v_1,...,v_n$ form an orthogonal
>   basis for their span W = $span(v_1,...,v_n )\subset V$, which is
>   therefore a subspace of dimension n = dimW. In particular, if dimV =
>   n, then $v_1,...,v_n$ form a orthogonal basis for V.

How will I be able to prove this theorem?

Comment: Well they are already orthogonal and they span, so what else do you need to show?  If $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0$, consider what happens when you take the inner product of both sides with $v_i$.

Comment: I have to show that they are linearly independent? So, I must show that $c_i = <u,v_i>$ ?

Comment: If $u = c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n$ and if the $v_i$ were *orthonormal*, then yes, you would show that $c_i = \langle u, v_i \rangle = 0$.  But you don't need the $v_i$'s to be orthonormal to prove that they are linearly independent; you just need they are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ is mutually orthogonal, $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ is an independent linear system in $V$. Since $dim V=n$ (equal number of elements of $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$) then $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.

To show that $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ is independent linear system we consider
$$
a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n=0, 
$$
where $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$. We have
$$
a_1\langle v_1, v_1\rangle + a_2\langle v_1, v_2\rangle+\ldots+a_n\langle v_1, v_n\rangle=0.
$$
Hence $a_1\langle v_1, v_1\rangle=0$ due to the fact that
$$
\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=\langle v_1,v_3\rangle=\ldots=\langle v_1,v_n\rangle=0.
$$. Since $v_1\ne 0$, we have $a_1=0$. Argue similarly we obtain $a_2=a_3=\ldots=a_n=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! So, essentially, I just have to show that they are linearly independent?

Answer (score 0):

you need to show that if $c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n = 0$ then $c_1=...=c_n = 0$ (shows linear independence). Maybe try a dot product on the first equation

Comment: So, I must show that $c_i = <u,v_i>$